# Injecting JpaRepository: Error creating bean with name - Not a managed type:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have problem with properly injecting JpaRepository to data provider. Try to add @EntityScan and @EnableJpaRepositories but still cannot inject the JpaRepository

```
package com.tablehop.tablehop_restaurant_app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.tablehop.tablehop_restaurant_app" })
@EntityScan("com.tablehop.tablehop_restaurant_app.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.tablehop.tablehop_restaurant_app.repository")
public class TablehopRestaurantAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TablehopRestaurantAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Below is the entity file

```
package com.tablehop.tablehop_restaurant_app.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicInsert;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int userID;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phone_no")
    private String phone_no;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
```

Also the repository file

```
package com.tablehop.tablehop_restaurant_app.repository;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.tablehop.tablehop_restaurant_app.entity.User;

@Repository
public interface userRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

//    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
//    @Transactional
//    @Query(value="update user set address = ?2 WHERE user_id = ?1", nativeQuery=true)
//    public void updateAddress(String userID, String address);
}
```

When I try to build the spring-boot, it return this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.tablehop.tablehop_restaurant_app.repository.userRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on TablehopRestaurantAppApplication: 
Not a managed type: class com.tablehop.tablehop_restaurant_app.entity.User
```

Is there any reference that I can refer to in order to solve this problem. Have been struggling for this for a long time.

Comment: Let me guess Spring Boot 3?

Comment: Appologies, the version is 3.1.2

Comment: Then why are yuo using `javax.persistece` instead of `jakarta.persistence`? Replace `javax.persistence` with `jakarta.persistece` remove the `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` after wards (as well as the `scanBasePackages`).

Comment: oh my god, thank you so much, the last version I used is quite old, and for this new project, I just decided to use the newer version, but didn't notice on the javax.persistece is being replaced by jakarta.persistence. Anyway, thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

In general I wouldn't recommend to use `user` as table name. `user` is often a keyword in database technologies. I recreated your code using a Postgresql database and it fails on the use of `user`. If you change the tablename to `userentity` for example the problem is resolved.

Here's the recreated example: https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-injecting-jpa-repository